# WordCloud on sentimental analysis

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to run this code on R-studio, which is on sentimental analysis.

**wordcloud(positive_tweets$Review, max.words = 100, scale = c(3,0.5))**

But every time I run it, I get the following code:

*Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large*

In addition to the warning message, R-studio is displaying the following:

*1: In tm_map.SimpleCorpus(corpus, tm::removePunctuation) :*
*transformation drops documents*
*2: In tm_map.SimpleCorpus(corpus, function(x) tm::removeWords(x, tm::stopwords())) :*
*transformation drops documents.*

Is there any other way that I can fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try it

```
wordcloud = WordCloud(width = 3000, height = 2000, background_color='black', 
max_words=100,colormap='Set2',stopwords=stopwords).generate(positive_tweets)

#Plot
plot_cloud(wordcloud)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Can you elaborate on what is different in your solution?  Code looks good but you can help us more with a bit more explaining.

Comment: Its not that much different. In wordcloud, I have just gave `stopwords in stopwords.txt`  to keyword stopwords and after that i have set it  for `positive_tweets` and after that i used plot_cloud to generate plot.